# how to recover the uninstall wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress

I uninstall the WordPress installation on my subdomain now the main domain is not working.

[here is the screencast video.](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cqVDlh3oMI)

Comment: Have you check your trash directory, if the files are there then restore it. Otherwise contact with your server provider.

Comment: there are no files trash